# Нужны ли здесь запятые

Tags: запятая

Я, короче, запуталась. Нужны ли запятые после "затем" и "после": "Затем он чуть трясет головой..."; "А после он гипнотизирует меня взглядом..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятые не нужны, ЗАТЕМ и ПОСЛЕ здесь обычные наречия - обстоятельства.

Answer (score 0):

Указанные запятые не нужны.